# Tomar el atributo "name" de la etiqueta <a> y crear una lista de enlaces

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero tomar el valor del atributo `name` de todos los elemento `<a>` y luego crear una lista con los enlaces a estos.

Esto fue lo que intente:

```html
    <ul class="navcard" style="list-style-type: none;">
         <h5 class="card-header" style="cursor: pointer;">Navegaci&oacute;n</h5>
          <div class="card-body" >
           <h5 class="card-title">
            <script type="text/javascript">
              $(".anchor").ready(function() {
               var array = $('.anchor').atrr('name');
               for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                innerHTML('<li><a href="#' + array[i] + '"></a></li>');
               }
              })
             </script>
           </h5>
          </div>
         </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas haciendo una mezcla interesante de código entre JavaScript y código en JQuery, considero que deberías optar por solamente usar uno de los 2.

Ahora se supone que tu tienes *N cantidad de etiquetas `a`* por lo que hacer algo como esto para recuperarlas:

```
$(".anchor").attr("name");
```

No te devolverá un vector sino solamente 1 elemento, claramente no me manejo en JQuery pero creo que en todo caso lo que buscas es el [método `get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

Puedes tomar otro enfoque y desarrollarlo así:

- Dales una clase genérica a todos tus elementos `a`
- Declara una lista desordenada `lu` vacía
- Recupera con [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) todas tus etiquetas `a` por medio de la clase definida previamente
- Recupera por medio de su clase a la lista desordenada
- Itera todas tus etiquetas `a` por medio de un ciclo [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach)
- Dentro de este ciclo, vas a crear un nuevo nodo `li`
- En su propiedad `innerText` le vas a asignar al `li` recién creado el valor del atributo `name` que estás recuperando
- Finalmente a la variable que representa a la lista desordenada le haces un [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) de los `li` recién creados

Código:

```html
    <a class="elementos" name="elemento1" href="">1</a>
    <a class="elementos" name="elemento2" href="">2</a>
    <a class="elementos" name="elemento3" href="">3</a>
    <a class="elementos" name="elemento4" href="">4</a>
    <a class="elementos" name="elemento5" href="">5</a>
    
    <ul class="listado">
      
    </ul>
    
    <script>
      let nombres = document.querySelectorAll('.elementos');
      let listado = document.querySelector('.listado');
      
      nombres.forEach((nombre) => {
        let elementoLista = document.createElement('li');
        elementoLista.innerText = nombre.name;
        listado.append(elementoLista);
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio, pero quiero; que es el objetivo crear no solo un nodo de lista, sino un nodo de enlace dentro de una lista y darle dichos valores obtenidos al atributo href del enlace.